# Importing Parse into a Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to build an application in Xcode using Parse as a backend. I am trying to initialize parse into the project but I am having some issues. I imported all the files needed and I create a Bridging-Header. I am now trying to enable the local datastore and add my application id and client key. The problem I need help with is understanding why my code for this process is not auto generating for me. When I type Parse and the dot symbol I am not getting any options. Can someone help me to figure out what is going on please!

```
import UIKit
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        Parse.enableLocalDatastore()
        // T66OsSCWrm1ldZc73N7NZYBtS6YaUFPcongNIEKl
        // F06Jg1mzOeBsTKNSCwkKSgbU1CpqcNKv5xUoD1ZI
         return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The key and token is not generated by the application you need to download it from the Parse website, you signed with Paser using the line below, with the values you copied from Parse.

```
    Parse.setApplicationId("Come from Parse", clientKey: "Come from parse")
```

Parse has complete support to Swift 1.2 and do not need header files, try to download the latest available SDK version for swift in the website.